# How to move between textviews inside tableview

Tags: ios, swift, text, textview

I have textview in tableview.I want to move to the next textview when return key is pressed.For now I'm able to scroll the tableview to next index but the state of active textview is not updating.

Here's the code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "editorCell", for: indexPath) as? EditorTableViewCell else{return UITableViewCell()}
    cell.textView.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pageCount
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.bounds.height
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    
    if textView.text.contains(where: {$0 == "\n"}){
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
        self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

In **textViewDidChange** I try to move to textview at index 1 but when I  type characters it gets written in textview at index 0.I'm unable to switch the active state of textview in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the text for each row.

```
var text0 = ""

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "editorCell", for: indexPath) as? EditorTableViewCell else{return UITableViewCell()}
    cell.textView.delegate = self
    cell.textView.text = self.text0
    return cell
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
  self.text0 = textView.text
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**CellForRow**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.textView.delegate = self
    cell.textView.text = "helllo \(indexPath.row)"
    cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}
```

**UITextViewDelegate**

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        let nextTextViewTag = textView.tag + 1
        for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
            if let nextTextView = cell.viewWithTag(nextTextViewTag) as? UITextView, let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
                nextTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
                tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```